# In U.S. is there any IP concern when my own company pays expenses for prototype development?

Tags: united-states, intellectual-property, business-expense

This question pertains to U.S. law, and California specifically if that matters.

Suppose person A founds a company that is owned by themselves and a trusted partner person B. Person A has a majority stake in it. Person A extends a loan of a few thousand dollars to the company to fund it and then pays from the company for parts for developing a prototype for an idea that person A intends to patent.

The understanding with the company and the person B was that person A would still own all of the intellectual property personally. While this understanding had not been codified in writing, let us suppose person B would be cooperative in this regard if it is necessary. Suppose the loan was in writing. Further let us suppose that person A is not employed at a different company or otherwise obligated to assign IP to anyone.

My question is whether it is proper and legal for person A to exclusively own the IP for the prototype given that the company has paid for the parts. Let us suppose that the parts cost is a very small fraction of the total economic cost of development of the prototype.

If so, is it necessary or advisable to get something in writing from the company or person B?

Also, given the circumstances that the company is not intended to own any of the IP, can it still be considered an ordinary and necessary business expense for the company to purchase the parts or would it be more appropriate for person A to reimburse the expenses to the company?

Comment: I think this is too close to legal advice, voting to close

Comment: @TigerGuy Is that a rule? How would it not apply to virtually every question on this forum. Would it help if I rewrote the question in "supposing" and hypothetical tone?

Comment: it is, and it might.

Comment: @TigerGuy Fixed.

Comment: I would appreciate if downvoters would leave comments explaining why. It could be something I could address given the opportunity.

Comment: My guess on the objections is that this question describes a convoluted situation (founding a company with somebody, funding it, having it purchase parts, then saying it shouldn't hold IP) with unwritten understandings (gigantic red flag) and then asks how to get out of it. It's not interesting to untangle messes caused by people who don't know what they're doing. Get a lawyer and pay them money to fix it.

Comment: @user71659 Dunno mate, that sounds like a pretty general objection that could be raised to virtually anyone that ended up in a bind and tried to ask a question about it. But I guess as a practical matter I will end up doing exactly that - paying a lawyer money to fix it.

Comment: You should take some time and note the other high-rated questions on this SE. They're more intellectually based, e.g. where does a certain British term come from, how does copyright apply to a court ruling, is it OK for a product to stop working after the warranty expires. The questions that describe a bind exist, but tend to have low ratings, particularly since individualized legal advice can't be given.

Comment: The site favors questions, the answers to which, might help people besides the OP. An answer to a convoluted situation is unlikely to be of use to others.

Comment: Besides being founders and owners are they considered employees of the company? If the company has nothing to do with the invention what is the motivation for the convoluted situation? Asking to get the question clarified and improved.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite The thinking was that the company would be involved in producing and marketing a product based on the invention, but without owning the IP itself, and only taking a minimal non-exclusive license that could be revoked at any time. It was thought to treat the prototyping costs as an expense for the company to be able to make some small tax saving (and in hindsight this seems to have been a poor decision that only causes trouble now with the IP status, but hopefully it is not too late to fix things). I am willing to reimburse the company or take the part costs as income for example.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Additionally to your other question, nobody is considered an employee of the company.

Comment: I guess if I were asked to trim back the convoluted scenario and boil this question down to it's essence, it would probably be: Is it valid for a company to provide a non-employee inventor with parts in exchange for a non-exclusive license that can be revoked at any time? If so, I believe person A would be in the clear, and it's just a matter of putting together company minutes that codify this situation. I worry, however, that a license that can be revoked at any time is legally equivalent to nothing, and would not constitute a valid agreement.

Comment: I have posted a more specific question here: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/97697/53339

Answer (score 2):

To this part of the question

> "If so, is it necessary or advisable to get something in writing from
> the company or person B?"

**Yes.**