# Is a non-exclusive and revocable license valid consideration for a legal agreement/contract?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, intellectual-property, california, consideration

This question pertains to U.S. law, and California law specifically, if it matters.

The motivation behind this question is the scenario where a company has supplied parts or equipment usage to a non-employee inventor in exchange for a non-exclusive and revocable license, in the event that a patent should issue on the invention, or in the event that copyright matter is produced. Is this a valid contract? If not, can the company later claim an interest in the invention and copyright matter?

I think the central and key issue is whether a non-exclusive and revocable license constitutes consideration.

Comment: @Jen License to produce and sell a product based on the invention, which would otherwise infringe the patent and license to use the copyright matter produced within the product (i.e., computer code).

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

You get to use something together with everyone else who buys a license until someone calls it off. That is more than a peppercorn, thus it is a valid consideration.